# DISTINCT multiple COLUMNS with IF

Tags: mysql, syntax, distinct, multiple-columns

saw lots of posts about it, but surprisly got SYNTAX problems
Here is code:

```
SELECT o.shortName AS '1'
      ,SUM(ai.amount) AS '3' 
      ,....
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT (IF (et.name LIKE 'lalala',ai.event_id,ai.action_id,ai.visit_id,NULL))) AS '6'
      ,...
      ,ROUND(SUM(ai.sum),2) AS '15'
  JOIN .... many tables
 GROUP BY o.id
```

Well, as u see IF wants 3 operands, but DISTNICT don't work with brackets.
 Can't use group by in the end.
Error msg: Operand should contain 1 column(s) <strike>cpt Obvios</strike>
P.S. mysql, INNODB

Comment: Well, tried to `COUNT(DISTINCT (IF (et.name LIKE 'Лечебно-диагностический',**CONCAT(ai.event_id,ai.action_id,ai.visit_id)**,NULL))))` but still not sure. Perhaps, should alter table add column

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Please attach expected result and sample data

Comment: this three columns is unique like id. i want check condition and count distinct rows.

Comment: Expected - unique rows. Sample data is difficlut coz of big query

Comment: CONCAT changed to CONCAT_WS(',',ai.event_id,ai.action_id,ai.visit_id). It will save me if id's will be like ...1-11..

Comment: Sample data is difficult? You simply create dummy values. There is no such thing as difficult sample data.

Comment: Ok. So this is  <br/>  SELECT ai.id,ai.event_id,ai.visit_id,ai.action_id,ai.sum   <br/>  FROM  account_item ai   <br/>  
  LIMIT 2 <br/>194404 7095 (null) 5900 291,54<br/>
194405 4919 (null) 3898 225,01  <br/>  what kind of data u need? how God damn break the line(

Comment: Before posting another question, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and some basic rules here on SO.

Comment: Sad, but true. Hope CONCAT_WS will help me to take distinct rows

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try using CONCAT_WS instead of CONCAT to avoid miscount when ids look similar, just like (1, 11, 111)

Comment: Yes, got it 10 min ago)

Comment: The process of migrating Vista workflow to stackoverflow has begun!